# IE has trouble with jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, effects

I'm using the following function, called from document.ready(), to set a fadeIn/fadeOut effect on the top navigation of [this](http://www.unctv.org/tWxkBbq_10M6wKRRL/x/home19_j.htm) page.

```
// Initialize the main menu's rollover behavior.
function initNavMenu(fadeInTime,fadeOutTime){
    $('#top-nav li').append('<div class="hover"></div>');

    $('#top-nav li').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).children('div').fadeIn(fadeInTime);
        },

        function(){
            $(this).children('div').fadeOut(fadeOutTime);
        }).click (function() {
            $('#top-nav li.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
}
```

It works well enough on FF 3.6.9, Chrome, Safari, and Opera. But on IE 8 (and probably lower versions), I get an ugly, smeared ink effect when I roll over the button. The smeared effect goes away once the fade is done. Anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: Ie does some ugly things with transparencies and .pngs are your background images png?

Comment: Yes, but I thought IE 7 and 8 should be able to handle them.

Comment: try saving those images as transparent gifs. I've run into similar ugliness with IE (even 7 and 8)  and had to change some of my pngs to gifs.

Comment: Thanks, Patricia. The only thing is the image uses a very smooth, semi-transparency, something you can't do well with GIFs.

Comment: yea, gifs are more limited unfortunately. but i haven't come up with any other way around it,  maybe someone else knows a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just see by Developer toolbar in IE after the control is visible due to fade effect it is adding some code for opacity. Just remove the piece of code by writing

```
$('selector').css('attribute', '');
or write 
$('selector').removeAttr('style'); // Removes all inline styles.
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks, Dev. Where in Developer Toolbar did you see this?

Comment: Just search for the particular item, search in IE toolbar and in the style tab you can find all its associated properties.

Comment: Thanks, Dev. Where would I add your code in the initNavMenu() function above?

Comment: In IE it adds 'filter' to change the opacity of the element. So after fadeIn effect it keeps the filter css attribute as it is so after the line $(this).children('div').fadeIn(fadeInTime) you can write code to remove it.